# Entity in database is null after post using react form. Why?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, crud

Good evening,
I'm trying to handle basic crud operations using React JS and Spring Boot.
I'm having issues inserting a new entity in the database: when I submit values in the form the entity in the database has only null values.

Here's the entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Calciatore {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    private String cognome;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Procuratore procuratore;

    private String ruolo;

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Squadra squadra;
}
```

Here's the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import toast from 'react-hot-toast'
import { url_backend_addCalciatore } from '../config'

export default class AddCalciatore extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      nome: "",
      cognome: "",
      ruolo: "",
    }

    this.addCalciatore = this.addCalciatore.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  }


  handleChangeNome = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      nome: event.target.value
    })
  }



  handleChangeCognome = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      cognome: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handleChangeRuolo = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      ruolo: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  }



  //POST
  addCalciatore = async () => {
    const calciatoreData = {
      nome: this.state.nome,
      cognome: this.state.cognome,
      ruolo: this.state.ruolo,
    }

    await axios.post(`${url_backend_addCalciatore}`, calciatoreData).then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        toast.success("Dati inseriti con successo.")
      }
    })

  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="card-header">
        Nuovo calciatore:
      </div>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">Nome</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value={this.state.nome} onChange={this.handleChangeNome} />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1" className="form-label">Cognome</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" value={this.state.cognome} onChange={this.handleChangeCognome} />
          </div>
          <br/>
          <select value={this.state.ruolo} onChange={this.handleChangeRuolo}>
            <option value="Portiere">Portiere</option>
            <option value="Difensore">Difensore</option>
            <option value="Centrocampista">Centrocampista</option>
            <option value="Attaccante">Attaccante</option>
          </select>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" disabled={!this.state.nome || !this.state.cognome} onClick={this.addCalciatore}>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm new to React JS so there might be terrible things written in my code. Hope you won't insult me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the part for saving the entity?

Comment: @pL4Gu33 I handle the post request using Axios library.


 OnSubmit I call the AddCalciatore method which should post data calling backend.


 addCalciatore = async () => {
    const calciatoreData = {
      nome: this.state.nome,
      cognome: this.state.cognome,
      ruolo: this.state.ruolo,
    }

    await axios.post(`${url_backend_addCalciatore}`, calciatoreData).then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        toast.success("Dati inseriti con successo.")
      }
    })

  }

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your method that creates your entity and performs the save has a transaction. Try adding a @Transactional on top of that method.